# Best way to refactor nested 'with patch' statements

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch

I am trying to patch out the Azure Digital Twin API in my code. Currently I have achieved a way which works but is probably not the most Pythonic by nesting `with patch` statements.

What is the best way to rewrite this such that I can use it in multiple test functions and change the return values if needed?

```
def test_create_digital_twin(self):
    
    with patch("endpoints.digital_twin.ClientSecretCredential"):
        with patch("azure_digital_twin.create_digital_twin.DigitalTwinsClient.query_twins",) as mock_query:
            with patch("azure_digital_twin.create_digital_twin.DigitalTwinsClient.upsert_digital_twin") as mock_upsert_twin:
                with patch("azure_digital_twin.create_digital_twin.DigitalTwinsClient.upsert_relationship") as mock_upsert_relationship:
                    
                    mock_query.return_value = [] 

                    mock_upsert_twin.return_value = {
                        "$dtId":"spc-1", 
                        "$etag":"random", 
                        "$model":"dtmi:digitaltwins:rec_3_3:core:Asset;1"
                    }
                    mock_upsert_relationship.return_value = {
                        "$relationshipId":"spc-1-hasPart-spc-2", 
                        "$sourceId":"spc-1",
                        "$targetId" : "spc-2",
                        "$relationshipName":"hasPart"
                    }
                    response = self.client.post(
                        endpoint,
                        params={"node" : "spc-1"},
                    )
    
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use an `ExitStack` from the `contextlib` module.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack



def test_create_digital_twin(self):
    with ExitStack() as es:
        def make_azure_patch(x):
            return es.enter_context(patch(f'azure_digital_twin.create_digital_twin.DigitalTwinsClient.{x}'))

        es.enter_context("endpoints.digital_twin.ClientSecretCredential"))
        mock_query = make_patch("query_twins")
        mock_upsert_twin = make_patch("upsert_digital_twin")
        mock_upsert_relationship = make_patch("upsert_relationship")
                
        mock_query.return_value = [] 

        mock_upsert_twin.return_value = {
            "$dtId":"spc-1", 
            "$etag":"random", 
            "$model":"dtmi:digitaltwins:rec_3_3:core:Asset;1"
        }
        mock_upsert_relationship.return_value = {
            "$relationshipId":"spc-1-hasPart-spc-2", 
            "$sourceId":"spc-1",
            "$targetId" : "spc-2",
            "$relationshipName":"hasPart"
        }
        response = self.client.post(
            endpoint,
            params={"node" : "spc-1"},
        )

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
```

`make_azure_patch` is just a helper function to reduce the length of the lines creating three of the individual patches.